# Regular Expression matching floating point numbers not ending with

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract CSS positions from a string - example:

```
"top left bottom right center 0 0% 50% 100% 360deg 15.5% -16.3%"
```

The problem is that the string also contains an angle "360deg".  I don't want any numbers followed by "deg" to be matched by the regular expression.  Currently, I have:

```
(-?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+))|(center)|(top)|(left)|(bottom)|(right)
```

This matches all the numbers (inc. the angle - which I don't want).  I have tried using a negative lookahead:

```
(-?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+))(?!deg)|(center)|(top)|(left)|(bottom)|(right)
```

But this only appears to remove the ending zero from 360deg - i.e. 360deg => 36

Does anyone know why the negative lookahead is not successful in removing the angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression matches because it found two digits not followed by "deg": The `36` is followed by `0` and that isn't "deg". The `[0-9]*` is usually greedy but if this causes the match to fail it will try alternatives matching fewer digits.

You can change the negative lookahead to this:

```
(?!deg|[0-9.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your word boundry:

```
(-?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)\b)|(center)|(top)|(left)|(bottom)|(right)
```